# Should this question(upgrade this or that) be on hold?

Tags: discussion

The following question was open for a year and a half and is now [On Hold]:

[Should I upgrade my body or lens first?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/40217/should-i-upgrade-my-body-or-lens-first)

It is a quite common question of a new photographer to start to get interested in upgrades... should I upgrade this or that first? This is an example of one such question that we have on the site, but there are others:

- [Should I upgrade my camera or my lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20441/should-i-upgrade-my-camera-or-my-lenses)
- [Should I upgrade my Canon Digital Rebel XTi?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3875/should-i-upgrade-my-canon-digital-rebel-xti)
- [Which should be the next upgrade?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45703/which-should-be-the-next-upgrade)
- [Should I upgrade my Canon body or lens for upcoming travel?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50792/should-i-upgrade-my-canon-body-or-lens-for-upcoming-travel)
- [Should I upgrade my camera or lens to shoot pro hockey games?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16863/should-i-upgrade-my-camera-or-lens-to-shoot-pro-hockey-games)
- [Should I consider spending more money now on a body if I don't plan on upgrading anytime soon?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13096/should-i-consider-spending-more-money-now-on-a-body-if-i-dont-plan-on-upgrading)
- [Is it lenses which make your photographs, not camera bodies?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18394/is-it-lenses-which-make-your-photographs-not-camera-bodies)
- [Camera vs. Lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52686/camera-vs-lens)
- [Which piece of equipment is holding me back?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10785/which-piece-of-equipment-is-holding-me-back)
- [Should i spend on upgrading my Beginner Camera or go for a new Lens instead?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59776/should-i-spend-on-upgrading-my-beginner-camera-or-go-for-a-new-lens-instead)

I've offered my own answer to the question that generally speaks to a much more broad audience regardless of brand, existing equipment, or really skilset.  Can we further generalize this one(or do we already have that?) so we can mark new ones as duplicates of this? Five people voted to close as too broad, but I argue that broad is what this question needs so we don't have every flavor ever of the question when really a broad answer is suitable.

Comment: I don't think it's too broad. It can be answered quite reasonably in my view. I've voted to reopen which means it's open.

Comment: Done now, but FWIW I agree too.